# Drawing a texture of arbitrary size in XNA

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

I wish to know if there is a way to load a texture which is not in powers of 2, for example 100 X 56 in dimension, in XNA 4.0 and draw it using VertexPositionColorTexture.

Comment: Not sure about VertexPositionColorTexture, but this can be done with SpriteBatch and Texture2D.

Answer (score 6):

It's very simple using SpriteBatch.
Initialize it :

```
spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(yourGraphicsDevice);
```

When you load content just call

```
image = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"yourImage");
```

then you can draw it easily

```
spriteBatch.Begin();
spriteBatch.Draw(image, dstRect, srcRect, Color.White);
spriteBatch.End();
```

That's all !

srcRect is juste a rectangle that indicates where your image is in the texture. That way you can have multiple images in one texture.

For the VertexPositionColorTexture, you'll probably want to create your own spriteBatch. See [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/xnaframework/thread/7e5cc12f-3b75-49ef-8da9-c00a75139a21/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Minishlink. Yes, I know how to do that in spritebatch. Sorry, I didn't mention that. The link to create a custom spritbatch looks interesting. I will surely try that. Thanks again!

Comment: The example I gave you is a bit old unfortunately, so you might want to take a look at a more recent piece of code. :)